# Appending stored estimates to tex output -- without separate tables/row headers

Tags: stata, tex

Issue: concatenating estimation results that arise in different programs into TeX output without repeating row header information and separating the table.

MWE below--but imagine my constraint is that I cannot combine the different estimations into the same program (different datasets, lots of processing in between) but nonetheless want the models to appear in the output like they do when storing estimates from specifications within the same program; i.e., I want to append to the existing output, written to disk in the first step, seamlessly and to appear in-line with common row labels (as applicable here), footer, proper column numbering, etc). Based on the nature/structure of TeX this might not be possible directly, but perhaps someone knows of a workaround?

```
sysuse auto, clear
/* uncomment and run this line if not already installed */ 
*ssc install estout

eststo clear
eststo: reg price mpg
esttab _all using temp.tex, style(tex) replace
exit, clear
```

(Start new Stata session.)

```
sysuse auto, clear
g ln_price = ln(price+1)
eststo clear
eststo: reg ln_price mpg
esttab _all using temp.tex, style(tex) append
*note that temp.tex clearly shows the appended regression estimates will be compiled in a different "table" separate from the first set, rather than in-line
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you want (if I understand correctly) using the `estimates save` command. Instead of saving a preliminary `.tex` file, save preliminary results using Stata's `.ster` files (that's the default extension). When you're done with estimations, bring the saved results back to memory and use them to tabulate.

An example below:

```
// load dataset #1
sysuse auto, clear

// run and save results to file
estimates clear
reg price mpg
estimates save price_eq

// load dataset #2
sysuse auto, clear
g ln_price = ln(price+1)

// run and store results in memory
estimates clear
reg ln_price mpg
estimates store lnprice_eq

// bring back results from file and store in memory
estimates use price_eq
estimates store price_eq

// tabulate regression results
esttab price_eq lnprice_eq using temp2.tex, style(tex) replace
```

(I'm assuming you are sure that `estimates store` alone can't handle the task.)